# Android Google Maps V2 API color banding with filled polygon

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

This is happening on Android using the Google Maps API V2.
If you draw a polygon using Paint and Path using moveTo(), lineTo() and drawPath() using FILL:

[image]

If you scroll around the map to the opposite side of the Earth from where the polygon is, you see this banding, with the color matching the FILL color:

[image]

There is no "leakage" from the polygon, it's fully closed point wise. And you don't see lines running out of it in any direction, and the Path and Paint settings are normal, nothing weird going on with that.
So why is this banding appearing?  I never noticed it before because I didn't bother to scroll to the other side of the Map.

Everything else I'm seeing with banding issues are from images, and this isn't that case.

So what can I try to fix this?  This on Windows and I'm not using Android Studio.
Too much code to try to show it.

UPDATE: I did find a way to "fix" it though.
I figure out when not to draw the polygon,
so it's not drawn, and there is no graphical glitch.

Thanks!